# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maps

Tags: python, pygmaps

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import pygmaps
import webbrowser

mymap = pygmaps.maps(37.428, -122.145, 16) 
mymap.setgrids(37.42, 37.43, 0.001, -122.15, -122.14, 0.001)
mymap.addpoint(37.427, -122.145, "#0000FF")
mymap.addradpoint(37.429, -122.145, 95, "#FF0000")
path = [(37.429, -122.145),(37.428, -122.145),(37.427, -122.145),(37.427, -122.146),(37.427, -122.146)]
mymap.addpath(path,"#00FF00")
mymap.draw('./mymap.draw.html')
url = './mymap.draw.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

But I get this error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maps'

I am using this alongside the module "pygmaps.py" 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `pygmaps.pygmaps()` instead of `pygmaps.maps()`

Comment: @putonspectacles Still the same error comment.  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GeoPy3.py", line 7, in <module>
    mymap = pygmaps.pygmaps(37.429, -122.145, 16) 
AttributeError: class pygmaps has no attribute 'pygmaps'
"

Comment: I figured it out. It was "mymap = pygmaps(37.429, -122.145, 16) "

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I searched  for an answer and I found that you have to add the `pygmaps` to your project and it will work without any problem

```
trace_map = pygmaps.maps(list_of_latitude[0], list_of_longitude[0], 16) 

#Initialize the pygmap variable with the first latitude and longitude values from corresponding lists
```

https://code.google.com/archive/p/pygmaps/downloads